# General strategy for processing files

Tags: python, file-io, preprocessor

I have a question not about particular realisation, but about some common coding practices for processing files: is it normal to load complete source file to memory?

For example, [here](https://github.com/Kronuz/pyScss/blob/master/scss/tool.py#L316) SASS source file is just loading to memory. I think it can cause a problems if size of this file will be more than 100Mb. Of course we can check extensions, or check filesize, or read file by chunks with fixed size or awaiting a good user intentions. As I see latter is most often choosed.

What do you think about it? How it realized in complex systems like gcc?

Comment: It does seem that the Sass are slightly naive in loading the complete source code all at once, but I guess that typically the file is going to hundreds of lines long and not thousands. So it's understandable what they do what they do. Parser design etc is outside my experience but parsers are usually streamable where they have limit 'look ahead'  capability but can build a model of what they've read. It's why languages complain about 'undefined symbols/functions' and you have to declare before using them. In all honesty I'm waiting for someone with more knowledge to answer :(

Comment: @sotapme yep, I have same thoughts. In case of pyScss it's user responsibility to give a normal file to preprocessor and user didn't wants to hung up his system, but in case of webservice this approach will vulnerable. At this moment I tend to read file by 512Kb chunks, drop unnecessary data and build some model of needed data. But it greatly complicates the whole architecture.